# What is the most cost-efficient method of making document writes/reads from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase's Cloud Firestore gives you limits on the number of document writes and reads (and deletes). For example, the spark plan (free) allows 50K reads and 20k writes a day. Estimating how many writes and reads is obviously important when developing an app, as you will want to know the potential costs incurred.

Part of this estimation is knowing exactly what counts as a document read/write. This part is somewhat unclear from searching online.

One document can contain many different fields, so if an app is designed such that user actions done through a session require the fields within a single document to be updated, would it be cost-efficient to update all the fields in one single document write at the end of the session, rather than writing the document every single the user wants to update one field?

Similarly, would it not make sense to read the document once at the start of a session, getting the values of all fields, rather than reading them when each is needed?

I appreciate that method will lead to the user seeing slightly out-of-date field values, and the database not being updated admittedly, but if such things aren't too much of a concern to you, couldn't such a method reduce you reads/writes by a large factor?

This all depends on what counts as a document write/read (does writing 20 fields within the same document in one go count as 20 writes?).

Comment: does writing 20 fields within the same document in one go count as 20 writes? - No, it's 1 write.

Comment: Read this to better understand Google's billing framework. [Understand Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost of a write operation has no bearing on the number of fields you write.  It's purely based on the number of times you call update() or set() on a document reference, weither independently, in a transaction, or in a batch.

If you choose to write each N fields using N separate updates, then you will be charged N writes.  If you choose to write N fields using 1 update, then you will be charged 1 write.